# React-Native nested Flatlist loop over 2 arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, reactive-programming

```
[
  {
    "User": 0,
    "UserGroupId": 0,
    "ContentType": "PhotoAlbums",
    "EventName": "Album Name",
    "ContentDescription": "Description",
    "ContentForIsAll": 3,
    "CollectionId": 0,
    "IsCommentable": true,
    "IsShareable": true,
    "IsStory": false,
    "IsHidden": false,
    "IsDeleted": false,
    "IsBlock": false,
    "CssClass": null,
    "Active": false,
    "PageId": 0,
    "EventStart": null,
    "EventEnd": null,
    "LastIpAddress": null,
    "CreatedOn": "2018-07-25T14:46:34.93",
    "LikeCount": 1,
    "ShareCount": 0,
    "CommentCount": 0,
    "PageIndex": 0,
    "PageSize": 0,
    "UserId": {
      "UserType": 0,
      "UserName": "admin@admin.com",
      "Password": null,
      "FirstName": "Administrator",
      "LastName": "-",
      "Address1": null,
      "Address2": null,
      "City": null,
      "StateProvince": null,
      "ZipPostalCode": null,
      "EmailAddress": null,
      "LocationName": null,
      "CompanyName": null,
      "Sex": null,
      "DateofBirth": null,
      "ProfileImage": "default_avatar.jpg",
      "DisplayImage": "default_avatar.jpg",
      "IsBlock": false,
      "RemainingEarningToken": 0,
      "IsOnline": false,
      "MobileNo": null,
      "IsMobileConfirm": false,
      "IsEmailConfirm": false,
      "IsForgotPass": false,
      "Active": false,
      "SystemName": null,
      "ConnectionId": null,
      "ParentId": null,
      "SaltKey": null,
      "ShareLink": null,
      "CssClass": null,
      "IsLikeAccess": false,
      "IsCommentAccess": false,
      "IsShareAccess": false,
      "LastIpAddress": null,
      "CreatedOnUtc": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "UpDatedOnUtc": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "LastLoginDateUtc": null,
      "LastActivityDateUtc": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "AccessToken": null,
      "PageIndex": 0,
      "PageSize": 0,
      "UserTypeId": null,
      "Id": 1
    },
    "PostDetailsEntityList": [ Want to display this array Path
      {
        "PostId": 8,
        "Name": "2018-07-25_02-46-34-PMchicken_rost.jpg",
        "Path": "2018-07-25_02-46-34-PMchicken_rost.jpg",
        "DetailContentType": "ImageText",
        "CreatedOn": "2018-07-25T14:46:34.987",
        "Id": 8
      },
      {
        "PostId": 8,
        "Name": "2018-07-25_02-46-34-PMcrispy.jpg",
        "Path": "2018-07-25_02-46-34-PMcrispy.jpg",
        "DetailContentType": "ImageText",
        "CreatedOn": "2018-07-25T14:46:34.987",
        "Id": 9
      },
      {
        "PostId": 8,
        "Name": "2018-07-25_02-46-34-PMdownload1.jpg",
        "Path": "2018-07-25_02-46-34-PMdownload1.jpg",
        "DetailContentType": "ImageText",
        "CreatedOn": "2018-07-25T14:46:34.987",
        "Id": 10
      },
      {
        "PostId": 8,
        "Name": "2018-07-25_02-46-34-PMdownload2.jpg",
        "Path": "2018-07-25_02-46-34-PMdownload2.jpg",
        "DetailContentType": "ImageText",
        "CreatedOn": "2018-07-25T14:46:34.987",
        "Id": 11
      }
    ],
    "PostCommentEntityList": [

    ],
    "Id": 8
  },
  {
    "User": 0,
    "UserGroupId": 0,
    "ContentType": "Event",
    "EventName": "Test Event",
    "ContentDescription": "Description\r\n",
    "ContentForIsAll": 3,
    "CollectionId": 0,
    "IsCommentable": true,
    "IsShareable": true,
    "IsStory": false,
    "IsHidden": false,
    "IsDeleted": false,
    "IsBlock": false,
    "CssClass": null,
    "Active": false,
    "PageId": 0,
    "EventStart": "2018-07-09T16:01:00",
    "EventEnd": "2018-07-17T17:01:00",
    "LastIpAddress": null,
    "CreatedOn": "2018-07-25T14:30:37.347",
    "LikeCount": 0,
    "ShareCount": 0,
    "CommentCount": 0,
    "PageIndex": 0,
    "PageSize": 0,
    "UserId": {
      "UserType": 0,
      "UserName": "admin@admin.com",
      "Password": null,
      "FirstName": "Administrator",
      "LastName": "-",
      "Address1": null,
      "Address2": null,
      "City": null,
      "StateProvince": null,
      "ZipPostalCode": null,
      "EmailAddress": null,
      "LocationName": null,
      "CompanyName": null,
      "Sex": null,
      "DateofBirth": null,
      "ProfileImage": "default_avatar.jpg",
      "DisplayImage": "default_avatar.jpg",
      "IsBlock": false,
      "RemainingEarningToken": 0,
      "IsOnline": false,
      "MobileNo": null,
      "IsMobileConfirm": false,
      "IsEmailConfirm": false,
      "IsForgotPass": false,
      "Active": false,
      "SystemName": null,
      "ConnectionId": null,
      "ParentId": null,
      "SaltKey": null,
      "ShareLink": null,
      "CssClass": null,
      "IsLikeAccess": false,
      "IsCommentAccess": false,
      "IsShareAccess": false,
      "LastIpAddress": null,
      "CreatedOnUtc": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "UpDatedOnUtc": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "LastLoginDateUtc": null,
      "LastActivityDateUtc": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "AccessToken": null,
      "PageIndex": 0,
      "PageSize": 0,
      "UserTypeId": null,
      "Id": 1
    },
    "PostDetailsEntityList": [
      {
        "PostId": 7,
        "Name": "2018-07-25_02-30-15-PMabba_ios_icon01_370x370.jpg",
        "Path": "2018-07-25_02-30-15-PMabba_ios_icon01_370x370.jpg",
        "DetailContentType": "ImageText",
        "CreatedOn": "2018-07-25T14:31:24.833",
        "Id": 7
      }
    ],
    "PostCommentEntityList": [

    ],
    "Id": 7
  }
]
```

Comment: I'm trying to display ContentDescription and PostDetailsEntityList[] Path in flatlist hear is my json response and flatlist

Comment: please 1) format your code properly, 2) add some context on what you are trying to do and the problem you have. don't forget to post the code you tried

Comment: Your code is unreadable, please provide readable and simple content https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve